# What is litre atm?

Tags: gas-laws

"The slope of a given straight line graph with constant temperature is found to be 0.2 l atm at 5 atmospheric pressure." What is l atm here? It is the unit of what?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\pu{L atm}$ is a unit of (pressure)(volume). As $\pu{atm}$ is a multiple of $\pu{N//m^2}$ and $\pu{L}$ is a multiple of $\pu{m^3}$, then $\pu{L atm}$ is a measure of joules, the unit of energy, which is $\pu{kg m^2//s^2}$ in base SI units.

Comment: you might also want to recall the gas law $pV=RT$ and the work done  (from thermodynamics) as $p\Delta V$; both have units of energy.

Answer (score 0):

$\pu{L atm}$ is a unit of pressure ($P$) times volume ($V$). As $\pu{atm}$ is the multiple of $\pu{N m-2}$. $\pu L$ is the multiple of $\pu{m3}$, then $\pu{L atm}$ is a multiple of Joules, the measure of energy, which is $\pu{kg m2/s2}$ in base SI units.